# XSLT-1.0: Merge and filter two XML files

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I need to conditionally merge two xml files with xslt-1.0. The first file is:

```
<rootnode>
 <section id="1" >
  <outer param="p1" >
   <inner />
   <inner />
  </outer>
  <outer >
   <inner />
  </outer>
  <outer />
  <outer />
 </section>
 <section id="3" >
  <outer >
   <inner />
   <inner />
   <inner />
  </outer>
 </section>
</rootnode>
```

The second file is:

```
$ cat res.xml 
<rootnode>
 <section id="1" status="fail">
  <outer param="p1" status="fail">
   <inner status="fail"/>
   <inner status="pass"/>
  </outer>
  <outer status="pass">
   <inner status="pass"/>
  </outer>
  <outer status="pass"/>
  <outer status="fail"/>
 </section>
 <section id="2" status="fail">
  <outer status="fail">
   <inner status="pass"/>
   <inner status="fail"/>
   <inner status="inc"/>
  </outer>
 </section>
 <section id="6" status="inc">
  <outer status="inc">
   <inner status="inc"/>
  </outer>
 </section>
</rootnode>
```

So far I have this XSLT file:

```
$ cat filter.xsl 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="doc" select="document('in.xml')"/>

<!-- part 1 -->
<xsl:template match="/">    
  <xsl:variable name="var" select="/rootnode/section" />
  <xsl:for-each select="$doc//section[not(@id = $var/@id)] ">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<!-- part 2 -->
<!--xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*[@status[not(normalize-space()='fail')]]"/>
<xsl:template match="@*[local-name() = 'status' "/-->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I use `xsltproc` to process the files

```
$ xsltproc filter.xsl res.xml
```

Part 1 will print the `section` nodes that are in `in.xml` and not in `res.xml`. If I comment out the part 1 and uncomment part 2 then I get the nodes from `res.xml` which have a `fail` status. I somehow need to combine those functionalities, i.e., I need to get all `section` nodes that are only in file `in.xml` and additionally all nodes from `res.xml` that have a `fail` status. The nodes are uniquely identified by their `id` attribute in `section`.

For above two files the result file would have to look like this:

```
$ cat final.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rootnode>
  <section id="1">
    <outer param="p1">
      <inner/>
    </outer>
    <outer/>
  </section>
  <section id="2">
    <outer>
      <inner/>
    </outer>
  </section>
  <section id="3">
    <outer>
      <inner/>
      <inner/>
      <inner/>
    </outer>
  </section>
</rootnode>
```

Comment: It's not possible to concatenate the two input files before processing with xslt? Maybe it will be easier.

Comment: After concatenation, you can apply Muenchian grouping and filtering. www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: On cursory look, both look like same structure with first one hardly without data. Why not just transform second to align to first?